# How to set multiple variables in a FOR loop?

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

I'm programming in Swift and I'd like to set up a couple of variables in a single loop.
These are UIButtons and they all require the same settings. However I don't know how to refer to these variables using "i". This is what I tried:

```
var gg1:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
var gg2:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
var gg3:UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton

//further in the code
for i in 1...3 {
    gg(i).layer.anchorPoint.x = 0
    gg(i).titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 20*rightFontSize)
    gg(i).setTitleColor(UIColor.blueColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    gg(i).sizeToFit()
    gg(i).center = CGPointMake(w/20,11*h/10)
    scrollView.addSubview(gg(i))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The buttons need to be in an array, for example:

```
let buttons = [gg1, gg2, gg3]
```

You can then use a `for` loop like so:

```
for button in buttons {
    // Setup the button...
    scrollView.addSubview(button)
}
```

Or, to shorten this a little:

```
for button in [gg1, gg2, gg3] { /* Setup */ }
```

Alternatively, if the buttons are all initialised the same way (and you need an array of buttons) you could do:

```
var buttons: [UIButton] = []
for i in 0..<3 {
    let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
    // Setup the button...
    buttons.append(button)
    scrollView.addSubview(button)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create array of buttons:

```
let array = [gg1, gg2, gg2]

for i in array.count
{
   //do something 
   array[i]
}
```

Comment: If the answer solved your problem you should consider accpeting it.

Answer (score 0):

You could nicely do:

```
[gg1,gg2,gg3].map({(button:UIButton) -> UIButton in     
   // Configure the buttons
   return button
})
```